# What is the impact of replicas field while updating existing Deployments in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

i'm trying to understand the kubernetes Deployment strategy by applying minReadySeconds and readinessprobe to the existing Deployment.But Getting different results If i have mentioned replicas field.
existing deployment manifest as below:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
 name: kubia-dep
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: dev
 template:
  metadata:
    name: dep-spec
    labels:
     app: dev
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: kubia-dep-cn
     image: luksa/kubia:v2
```

Deployment and pod status as below

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get deployments
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubia-dep   3/3     3            3           30s
[root@master ~]#

[root@master ~]# kubectl get po
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia-dep-54cd566dc8-4vbjq   1/1     Running   0          113s
kubia-dep-54cd566dc8-kssrb   1/1     Running   0          113s
kubia-dep-54cd566dc8-vgjpv   1/1     Running   0          113s
[root@master ~]#
```

Now i'm applying minReadySeconds,readinessProbe and updating image as luksa/kubia:v3 which having the code as All http requests from the fifth request onward will return an internal server error (HTTP status code 500) to test the benefits of combination of minReadySeconds,readinessProbe

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
 name: kubia-dep
spec:
 replicas: 3
 minReadySeconds: 10
 selector:
  matchLabels:
   app: dev
 strategy:
  rollingUpdate:
   maxSurge: 1
   maxUnavailable: 0
  type: RollingUpdate
 template:
  metadata:
   name: dep-spec
   labels:
    app: dev
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: kubia-dep-cn
     image: luksa/kubia:v3
     readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
       path: /
       port: 8080
      periodSeconds: 1
```

Deployment status,pod status as below

```
[root@master ~]# kubectl get deployments
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubia-dep   0/3     3            0           9m4s
[root@master ~]#

[root@master ~]# kubectl get po
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubia-dep-7c884d659-h4svd   0/1     Running   0          6m3s
kubia-dep-7c884d659-nrwdf   0/1     Running   0          6m5s
kubia-dep-7c884d659-wmzfk   0/1     Running   0          6m8s
[root@master ~]#
```

Now no pods are in ready status.I mean like all 3 pods are having the bug image version and if i hit the curl i'm getting

```
while true;do curl http://10.104.60.165;done
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.104.60.165:80; Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.104.60.165:80; Connection refused
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.104.60.165:80; Connection refused
```

**expectation:**
Until the first new v3 pod is available, the rollout process will not continue and existing v2 pods will serve the incoming requests

**Actual:**
3 pods with new buggy v3 versions are running and making all connections to apps as refused

So is this is the impact of replicas field mentioned while updating the existing deployment?.If so how it is working?

Comment: Any changes in deployment lead to all pods re-deployment. So, if you changing something using 'kubectl edit deployment' or through the dashboard for example, it is not correct way. The best way to reach the result without an impact for your services, it is use `kubectl scale deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment --replicas=10` scale syntax. Additional information you can find by link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#scaling-a-deployment

Comment: I don't see the same behavior. I ran your first deployment and saw three ready replicas. I then applied deployment 2 and say the rolling update halt as the first pod of the new version went unready before the minReadySeconds time. It then stayed in this state leaving the original replicas running.

Comment: Can't see the same behavior either. Can you provide information about cluster setup and your environment?

Comment: [root@master ~]# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.56.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
[root@master ~]# kubectl get no
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
master.k8s   Ready    master   3d22h   v1.16.2
node1.k8s    Ready    <none>   3d20h   v1.16.3
node2.k8s    Ready    <none>   3d19h   v1.16.3
[root@master ~]#     installed using kubeadm on rhel 7

Comment: Could you provide output from `kubectl describe deployment kubia-dep` and `kubectl rollout history deployment/kubia-dep` ?